# Why cant we pass a named function instead of a anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

I have some experience with javascript already, but I have a doubt for quite a while: why can't you pass a named function to places where it is expected an anonymous function to execute a piece of code? ie:

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('Hello World');
});
```

Now let's say I already have a function that does this.

```
var func = function(){
    alert('Hello World');
}
```

Why it isn't executed as a callback to the click event?

```
 document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', func);
```

it seems redundant to create a anonymous function to then call a named function:

```
 document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
     func();
 });
```

Comment: You **can** pass a named function, exactly as you describe.

Comment: Your example isn't a named function and if it does not work it has nothing to do with the fact that you put it in a variable.

Comment: whatever you have here, should work. I still am wondering what do u mean when you say,  *it seems redundant to create a anonymous function to then call a named function:*

Comment: To put it another way, nothing "expects" an anonymous function; that doesn't make any sense in JavaScript. If something expects a function, it expects a function, and there's no difference in that context between one that happens to be anonymous and one that isn't.

Comment: `document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', func);` works without any problem...

Comment: check your console for errors

Comment: Could be use of var to declare your function.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: @Pointy Wrong, there _is_ a difference. The API can check for the `name` property of the function. But that's a dumb thing to do. Like, double dumb...

Comment: @Kyll fine, but that just tells it whether the function was defined with a name; it says nothing about whether the function was instantiated as part of the API call or instead was declared/defined elsewhere. Also, as you say, it's pointless :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to take a look at your full code, but you CAN pass a function as a variable.

```
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', function(){
alert('Hello World');
});


var func = function(){
   alert('Hello World, it is me again.');
};

document.getElementById('button2').addEventListener('click', func);
```

Check out the fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/b4ktmp09/

Could you possibly be declaring the variable for the function (func) in the wrong spot in your code, causing it to be null?

Comment: Not `null`, but `undefined`.